# Django テンプレートにブレークポイントを付けたい

Tags: python, django, vscode

## 質問

VS Code でdjangoをデバッグしているのですが、
テンプレートでブレイクポイントを設定する方法はないのでしょうか？
テンプレート以外のmodels.pyやviews.pyは問題なく可能です。

テンプレートのレンダリング時にエラーが発生すると、
テンプレート内の行でブレーキがかかるので、
出来ないことはないと思います。
しかし、行番号横のクリックやF9、右クリックメニューのいずれもできません。

何か設定があるのでしょうか？

[image: django template debuging on vscode]

## launch.json

```json
{
    // IntelliSense を使用して利用可能な属性を学べます。
    // 既存の属性の説明をホバーして表示します。
    // 詳細情報は次を確認してください: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Django",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\manage.py",
            "args": [
                "runserver",
                "--noreload",
                "--nothreading"
            ],
            "django": true
        }
    ]
}
```

## settings.json

```json
{
    "python.pythonPath": "C:\\tools\\miniconda3\\envs\\dj\\python.exe"
}
```

## 使用している拡張機能

- Anaconda Extension Pack
- Auto Close Tag
- Auto Rename Tag
- Beautify
- Bracket Pair Colorizer
- Django
- EJS language support
- EJS Sunippets
- ES Lint
- Formatting Toggle
- Git History
- Git Lens
- indent-rainbow
- Japanese Language Pack for Visual Studio Code
- Path Intellisense
- Python
- SQLite
- Visual Studio IntelliCode

## 使用環境

- Windows10 Pro 1903
- Miniconda3 4.6.14
- Django2.2.2

#### VScode

- バージョン: 1.35.1 (user setup)
- コミット: c7d83e57cd18f18026a8162d042843bda1bcf21f
- 日付: 2019-06-12T14:30:02.622Z
- Electron: 3.1.8
- Chrome: 66.0.3359.181
- Node.js: 10.2.0
- V8: 6.6.346.32
- OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.18362

Comment: [このページ](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/tutorial-django#_use-the-debugger-with-page-templates)で紹介されていますが、この通りブレークポイントが設定できないということですか？

Comment: @KoheiTAMURA  そうです。` when you have "django": true in the debugging configuration`とありますが、Trueになっています。launch.jsonはデバッグ時に自動生成された元をそのまま使用しています。

Comment: settings.json と launch.json を質問本文に追記しました。

Comment: 始めてVSCodeでDjangoを動かしてみましたが、特に設定はせずに、テンプレートに設定したブレークポイントで止まり、変数の中身が見れました。Ubuntu系のOSを使い、VSCodeのバージョンは1.35.1でした。Python extensionくらいしか追加でインストールしていないです。`launch.json`の該当箇所の差異は`"console": "integratedTerminal",`だけでした。これが関係あるのかなぁ...(消してもデバッグはできましたが)

Comment: @KoheiTAMURA 検証ありがとうございます。そうなると、拡張機能かOS固有の問題かどちらかな可能性が大きいですね

Comment: んー、どうなんでしょう。行番号の横をクリックしてもブレークポイントの赤丸すら表示されないということですよね？

Comment: @KoheiTAMURA いろいろ拡張機能をON/OFFして試したのですが、[Django Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=batisteo.vscode-django)をOFFにした時だけ、ブレークポイントが設定できました。django extension をONにするとHTMLファイルがDjango-HTMLという形式として認識されて、その間はブレークポイントが使えませんでした。githubでissue挙げてみます。

Comment: Django Extensionが逆に邪魔してたってことですか。それは思いつきませんね...